# If I have an event where the outcomes aren't uniformly distributed, how would I make the "fairest" bingo card out of the events?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

I think I should start by clarifying what I mean by "fairest". I mean that the probability of winning with any one line is as close as possible to winning with any of the others. Formally I want to know this:

Lets say you you have 25 independent outcomes to an event: $e_n$ with respective probabilities $p_n$, and  $p_1 \leqslant p_2 \leqslant ... \leqslant p_{25}$.

Take a 5x5 grid containing the elements $e_n$, label the straight lines of 5 grid points (horizontal, diagonal, and vertical) by $l_k$ for $1 \leqslant k \leqslant 12$.

Perform the event, cross out the gridpoint of $e_n$ if outcome $e_n$ occurs, and repeat the event until a full line in the 5x5 grid has been crossed out. if every grid point of $l_k$ has been crossed out, you have "won" with line $l_k$.

For a given 5x5 grid, let $Pl_k$ be the probability of winning with line $l_k$.

Is there a way to find the arrangement of outcomes $e_n$ into a 5x5 grid to minimise: $$sup_{1 \leqslant i,j \leqslant 12}{|Pl_i - Pl_j|}$$

How would I do this if the events aren't indepenent?

My intuition says that the best arrangement would be one of the 5x5 magic squares, replacing $n$ with $e_n$, but I can't justify that, and I doubt that would work if the events weren't independent.

Comment: There are 12 straight lines, not 10.

Comment: Wow that was dumb, was thinking of a 4x4 for some reason. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: On a more basic level, how would you even calculate $Pl_k$?  You may be able to calculate the probability of line $l_k$ being filled by $\le T$ moves, and from that the prob of the line being filled at exactly the $T$th move, but for the line to actually *win* this would also require the other $11$ lines being not yet filled - and that seems like a really difficult problem.

Comment: If you let $Pl_{i,t}$ be the probability of it being solved after t events, would trying to maximise the limit of $sup({ {Pl_{i,t} / Pl_{j,t}} | Pl_{i,t} \leqslant Pl_{j,t}})$ as t tends to infinity be the same as what I've said above? I was hoping there would be some kind of algorithm I was too dumb to find to help with this. I get calculating the probabilities separately would be too hard, but I couldn't see a better way to formulate it.

Comment: Actually, reading my last comment over, if the formulation is the same then wouldn't maximising that for any t>4 lead to the solution? Meaning that I'm just minimising the difference between the chance of getting one line after 5 tries and another line after 5 tries. They're then very easy numbers to work with

Comment: Well $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} Pl_{i,t} = 1$ for every line, so that wouldn't work...  :)  Personally I think that (in the independent case) $Pl_{i,5}$ are good proxies for what you want to equalize, i.e. equalizing them would also (at least roughly) equalize the line win chances.  But my gut feel $\neq$ what is provably true!  Anyway if you wanna equalize $Pl_{i,5}$ then you are filling a magic square with the entries being $\log p_n$ and trying to minimize the differences between line sums.  Maybe replacing $n$ with $e_n$ is already optimal but even that is unclear to me.

Comment: I think I originally had "for every t > some N" instead of "as t tends to infinity". Guess that's why you shouldn't edit comments. Intuitively I can't see how the grid that minimises $sup_{1 \leqslant i,j \leqslant 12}{|Pl_{i,5} - Pl_{j,5}|}$ couldn't be the grid I'm after, but I can't come up with a proof either way.

Comment: The more I think about this...there are actually some additional complications: Even if all $p_n = 1/25$, I don't think all 12 lines have equal chances of winning.  I have captured this (and some other observations) in a new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140502/do-the-12-lines-of-a-bingo-card-have-equal-chance-of-winning  Of course if all $p_n=1/25$ your assignment problem is solved :) but I'm just saying this is more complicated then we've so far discussed.

Comment: Yeah, assuming that's right, guess this is a very unrealistic question