# Expected number of rolls to win a modified Bingo game

Tags: probability, dice

Suppose I have a 5x5 Bingo card with each box numbered sequentially from 1 to 25, and a fair 25-sided die will be rolled repeatedly. How do I find the average number of rolls it would take for a 50% chance to hit Bingo?

Comment: A very interesting problem! I'm not sure how to go about solving it. What makes it tricky is that $16$ of the numbers are part of two bingos, $8$ are part of three, and $1$ is part of four. Rolling a $13$ gets you further along than rolling a $1$, and that gets you further along that rolling a $2$. Is this homework or just a curiosity?

Comment: This is not homework, this is actually a small game I've created for a group of friends and I was curious about the math behind it!

Comment: Maybe a potential way to find the answer is to brute force it? There's only 12 ways to get Bingo (5 horizontal, 5 vertical, 2 diagonal). Figuring out the expected number of trials for each of the 12 win conditions seems simple, but I'm not sure how to handle the overlaps to combine all the probabilities together to get the chance for a single win.

Comment: Let me know where you got the fair $25$-sided die – I'd like to have one, too :-)

Comment: @joriki Don't think a fair die with an odd number of sides is possible; you could use a 50-sided die (these exist) and then take the ceiling of half the number that shows up.

Comment: You might be interested in [my related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140502/do-the-12-lines-of-a-bingo-card-have-equal-chance-of-winning), which is about the even funkier issue of which line is more likely to win _first_.  Also @user3261567 - the winning times for each of the $12$ lines are identically distributed, and in particular have the same expected winning times, but since they are dependent it is not obvious how to get from that number to the OP problem.  I see no good way to approach this except simulation.